# Find Item.index after using Items.find

Tags: vba, indexing, outlook, find, items

How do you look up the index of a contact item that was set using the items.find method?  After finding the item, I want to be able to move to the next item, but my code sends me to the first item in the collection.  A condensed version of my plan is below...

```
dim ColItms as items
dim CI as contactItem
Dim CIindex as integer

set CI= ColItms.find("[CompanyName] = ""IBM""")
CIindex = CI.????  '''''  This shows what I'm wanting to do, but don't know how

' now advance to next item in collection
set ci = ColItms.item(CIindex +1) ' i think this would work if I could find CIindex

set ci = ColItms.GetNext ' this fails as it returns the 1st item in the collection
```

Right now all that seems to work is to loop through each item in the collection to see if it matches the found contact,

Answer (score 0):

Items have no intrinsic index, only an entry id.
To find the next match, use `Items.FindNext`.